# Comportamiento inesperado en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on("click", "#check-personalizado", function(){

    var check = $(this).attr("checked");

    if (!check) {
        var check = $(this).attr("checked", true);


        $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);


        $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);



        $(".div-comedor").hide();
        $(".div-dmc").hide();

        $(".agregarIngredientePersonalizado").removeClass("d-none");


    } else {
        var check = $(this).attr("checked", false);



        $(".div-comedor").show();
        $(".div-dmc").show();

        $(".agregarIngredientePersonalizado").addClass("d-none");
        $(".listaIngredientes").remove()


        $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);
        $("#check-comedor").prop("checked", false);


        $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);
        $("#check-dmc").prop("checked", false);





    }
})

/*============================================
HABILIAR Y DESHABILITAR SELECT COMEDORT Y DMC
==============================================*/

$(document).on("click","#check-comedor", function() {


    var check = $(this).attr("checked");

    if (!check) {
        $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", false);
        var check = $(this).attr("checked", true);


    } else {
        $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);
        var check = $(this).attr("checked", false);

    }
})


$(document).on("click","#check-dmc", function() {

    var check = $(this).attr("checked");

    if (!check) {
        $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", false);
        var check = $(this).attr("checked", true);


    } else {
        $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);
        var check = $(this).attr("checked", false);

    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Datos Comedor -->    
<div class="row div-comedor">
    <!-- Checkbox comedor -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="icheck-success">
          <input  type="checkbox" id="check-comedor" name="check-comedor">
          <label  class="text-dark" for="check-comedor">&nbsp;Comedor</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Select Menu Comedor-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">

        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i></span>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control ml-2" name="select-comedor" id="select-comedor" disabled>
          <option value="">Seleccionar Menu Comedor</option>
        </select>

      </div> 
    </div>

    <!-- Input cupos Comedor-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="0" id="cupos-comedor" readonly>
        <span class="small text-muted">Cupos Comedor</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="precioComedor" name="precioComedor"></input>
</div>

<!-- Datos DMC -->
<div class="row div-dmc mt-4">
      <!-- Checkbox DMC-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="icheck-danger">
          <input  type="checkbox" id="check-dmc" name="check-dmc">
          <label  class="text-dark" for="check-dmc">&nbsp;DMC</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Select Menu DMC-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">

          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-hotdog"></i></span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control ml-2" name="select-dmc" id="select-dmc" disabled>
            <option value="">Seleccionar Menu DMC</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Input cupos DMC-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="0" id="cupos-dmc" readonly>
        <span class="small text-muted">Cupos DMC</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="precioDmc" name="precioDmc"></input>
</div>

<!-- CREAR REMITO PERSONALIZADO -->
<hr>
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-6 form-group">
        <div class="icheck-warning">
          <input  type="checkbox" id="check-personalizado" name="check-personalizado">
          <label  class="text-dark" for="check-personalizado">&nbsp;Crear Remito Personalizado</label>
          </div><span class="small text-muted">Agregar al remito elementos que no pertenezcan a un menú</span>

    </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg agregarIngredientePersonalizado d-none">Agregar Producto</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

    <!-- ENTRADA PARA AGREGAR INGREDIENTES-->
    <div class="form-group ingredientesPersonalizados">


    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="ingredientesPersonalizadosFinal" name="ingredientesPersonalizadosFinal">

    <input type="hidden" name="precioPersonalizado" name="precioPersonalizado"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tengo un comportamiento inesperado en unos checkbox, estoy utilizando mal la lógica en javascript y no puedo ver el error. El tema es asi:

Tengo 3 checkbox (ver imagen al final de la pregunta), `check-dmc`, `check-comedor` y `check-personalizado`. Los dos primeros, por su parte, al clickearse habilitan un `select` y un `input` numérico (cada uno tiene su select y su input). El 3er check hace desaparecer los dos anteriores y crea un botón (este check habilitaria un `modo personalizado`).

Ahora, si yo salgo del modo `personalizado` dando uncheck al `check-personalizado`, vuelven a aparecer los dos primeros checks, reiniciados. Pero ya no se comportan como antes.

Ahora en lugar de habilitar un `select` y un `input`, el check que haya tenido estado checked true en el momento que se hace click en el 3er boton, funciona al reves (puede ser uno, el otro o ambos).

Se muestra uncheck y al clickear sobre él una vez, se checkea pero no cambia el select y el input. Un segundo click, se uncheckea y ahora se muestra el select y el input. El check empieza a funcionar al revés de su comportamiento original.

> Coloco el código de cada checkbox y adjunto una imagen para tratar de ilustrar lo que pasa,
>
> Check Comedor (1)

```
$(document).on("click","#check-comedor", function() {


var check = $(this).attr("checked");

if (!check) {
    $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", false);
    var check = $(this).attr("checked", true);


} else {
    $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);
    var check = $(this).attr("checked", false);

}
})
```

> Check DMC (2)

```
$(document).on("click","#check-dmc", function() {

var check = $(this).attr("checked");

if (!check) {
    $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", false);
    var check = $(this).attr("checked", true);


} else {
    $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);
    var check = $(this).attr("checked", false);

}
})
```

> Check personalizado (3)

```
$(document).on("click", "#check-personalizado", function(){

var check = $(this).attr("checked");

if (!check) {
    alert("hola")
    var check = $(this).attr("checked", true);


    $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);


    $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);



    $(".div-comedor").hide();
    $(".div-dmc").hide();

    $(".agregarIngredientePersonalizado").removeClass("d-none");


} else {
    alert("chau")
    var check = $(this).attr("checked", false);



    $(".div-comedor").show();
    $(".div-dmc").show();

    $(".agregarIngredientePersonalizado").addClass("d-none");
    $(".listaIngredientes").remove()


    $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#check-comedor").prop("checked", false);


    $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#check-dmc").prop("checked", false);





}
})
```

> Intenté resumir el comportamiento que sucede en estos 4 screenshots. Primero, la página inicia normal, con los checks desactivados y los inputs disabled. Puedo clickear en los checks y se comportan de acuerdo a lo esperado. Luego, si doy click en `Remito Personalizado`, y vuelvo a dar click (los dos primeros checks desaparecen y vuelven a aparecer) se comportan como indica el final (En ese caso se ve que el primer checkbox se está comportando al reves, pero si clickeo en el de abajo pasa exactamente lo mismo, debido a que estaba seleccionado cuando se dio click por primera vez al check 3)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo(a), que versión de Jquery estas ocupando?

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `$(document).on("click", "#check-personalizado")` en vez de `$("#check-personalizado").on("click")`?

Creo que deberías plantear los problemas poco a poco, o dar una url de ejemplo, es muy largo de seguir.

Comment: podrias utilizar la opcion `fragemento js/css` cuyo icono es `<>` para agreagar un ejemplo funcional del comportamiento inesperado del que hablas ya que tu pregunta no incluyes el codigo html requerido para las pruebas!

Comment: Lo estaba usando de la forma que indicas pero estuve probando varias cosas a ver si lo podia arreglar, y en una de esas cambie la linea que indicas, pero de todas maneras no cambio su comportamiento. La version de jQuery es la 3.4.1

Comment: listo @Bryro, agregue al inicio los dos fragmentos para que se pueda ejecutar, y se puede apreciar el error. Muchas gracias por la recomendacion

Comment: Ya, si puedes realizar esta prueba te lo agradecería, usa`prop` en vez de `attr`, algo así `$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);`, no es que sea un método deprecado, pero es así el jquery moderno

Comment: el codigo no se veria mejor algo como ` $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", !check);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", !check);`??

Comment: @JackNavaRow puede ser, estoy hace unos meses trabajando con esto de manera autodidacta, y tal vez no tenga mucha experiencia sobre "buenas practicas" y "clean code", pero de momento me preocupa mas la funcionalidad

Comment: Creo que para este tipo de casos es mejor que expliques lo que quieres hacer con simplicidad y brevedad y luego muestres el código diciendo: falla esto y esto.  Así podremos ayudarte a dar una mejor solución al problema. A veces uno se resigna a un código complicado, mal escrito, que emprende  un camino largo para resolver problemas simples. De acuerdo a lo que he entendido leyendo la pregunta el problema no es complicado, lo que es complicado es la forma en que lo quieres resolver. Si logras explicar el problema con claridad podremos proponerte una solución óptima...

Comment: @A.Cedano totalmente de acuerdo, esa cantidad de código es imposible. Por ello es tan importante el [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @A.Cedano los primeros dos bloques de código (que es lo que hace muy grande a la pregunta) los puse a pedido del user Bryro, que queria ver el problema que yo estaba teniendo, la pregunta tenia bastante menos codigo en un inicio. Igual gracias a todos, el problema fue resuelto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya estimado, creo que el error que tenías es cuando seteabas las propiedades `checked` de manera interna, es decir, si le das un atributo `checked` dentro de una detección de `check` tiende a mandar mensajes erróneos, por lo que te recomiendo mejor detectar el `"check-uncheck"` con la propiedad [Change](https://www.javatpoint.com/jquery-change) de Jquery

```js
$("#check-personalizado").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#select-comedor").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-comedor").prop("readonly", true);


    $("#select-dmc").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-dmc").prop("readonly", true);



    $(".div-comedor").hide();
    $(".div-dmc").hide();

    $(".agregarIngredientePersonalizado").removeClass("d-none");


  } else {

    $(".div-comedor").show();
    $(".div-dmc").show();

    $(".agregarIngredientePersonalizado").addClass("d-none");
    $(".listaIngredientes").remove()


    $("#select-comedor").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-comedor").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#check-comedor").prop("checked", false);


    $("#select-dmc").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-dmc").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#check-dmc").prop("checked", false);





  }
})

/*============================================
HABILIAR Y DESHABILITAR SELECT COMEDORT Y DMC
==============================================*/


$("#check-comedor").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", false);

  } else {
    $("#select-comedor").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-comedor").attr("readonly", true);

  }
})


$("#check-dmc").change(function() {

  if (this.checked) {
    $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", false);


  } else {
    $("#select-dmc").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#cupos-dmc").attr("readonly", true);

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Datos Comedor -->
<div class="row div-comedor">
  <!-- Checkbox comedor -->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 form-group">
    <div class="icheck-success">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check-comedor" name="check-comedor">
      <label class="text-dark" for="check-comedor">&nbsp;Comedor</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Select Menu Comedor-->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">

      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i></span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control ml-2" name="select-comedor" id="select-comedor" disabled>
        <option value="">Seleccionar Menu Comedor</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Input cupos Comedor-->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="0" id="cupos-comedor" readonly>
    <span class="small text-muted">Cupos Comedor</span>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="precioComedor" name="precioComedor"></input>
</div>

<!-- Datos DMC -->
<div class="row div-dmc mt-4">
  <!-- Checkbox DMC-->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 form-group">
    <div class="icheck-danger">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check-dmc" name="check-dmc">
      <label class="text-dark" for="check-dmc">&nbsp;DMC</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Select Menu DMC-->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">

      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-hotdog"></i></span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control ml-2" name="select-dmc" id="select-dmc" disabled>
        <option value="">Seleccionar Menu DMC</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Input cupos DMC-->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="0" id="cupos-dmc" readonly>
    <span class="small text-muted">Cupos DMC</span>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="precioDmc" name="precioDmc"></input>
</div>

<!-- CREAR REMITO PERSONALIZADO -->
<hr>
<div class="row mt-4">
  <div class="col-6 form-group">
    <div class="icheck-warning">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check-personalizado" name="check-personalizado">
      <label class="text-dark" for="check-personalizado">&nbsp;Crear Remito Personalizado</label>
    </div><span class="small text-muted">Agregar al remito elementos que no pertenezcan a un menú</span>

  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg agregarIngredientePersonalizado d-none">Agregar Producto</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

    <!-- ENTRADA PARA AGREGAR INGREDIENTES-->
    <div class="form-group ingredientesPersonalizados">


    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="ingredientesPersonalizadosFinal" name="ingredientesPersonalizadosFinal">

    <input type="hidden" name="precioPersonalizado" name="precioPersonalizado"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, funcionó a la perfección! Que renuncie pronto piñera!

Comment: Gracias a ti por tus deseos!